# kilo editorが非表示の文字のために9byteのメモリを割り当てようとする理由

Tags: c

kiloという1000行ほどで書かれたシンプルなエディタがあります

[kilo github page](https://github.com/antirez/kilo)

このコードを読んでいるのですが、551行目の意味がよくわかりません

```
551        row->render = malloc(row->size + tabs*8 + nonprint*9 + 1);
```

`nonprint*9`はnon-printableなcharのために9byteも割り当てています

しかも、543行目で`nonprint = 0`となっており、この行以外で`nonprint`の値が操作されることはありません (551行目では常に`nonprint = 0`となる)

```
543        int tabs = 0, nonprint = 0, j, idx;
```

551行目の`nonprint*9`にはどのような意図があるのでしょうか?

Comment: READMEファイルにこう記載されています。_The project is in alpha stage and was written in just a few hours_ 「このプロジェクトはまだアルファステージで、ほんの数時間で書かれたものなんです。」つまりまだまだ完成品にはほど遠いということです。世の中には「完成」とされているソフトの中でさえ、書きかけで放置されたか、消しかけで消し残されたコードが残っている場合があります。ましてやアルファ版のソフトに完全な整合性を求めるのは無理です。あなたが確認されているように現在のコードでは同関数内の`nonprint`はずっと0ですから全く意味を持ちません。「どのような意図があるのでしょうか?」というご質問なので、yohjpさんは同じコードの他の箇所の記述から、元はこのような意図で書かれたもの(の痕跡、名残)ではないかと推測されているわけで、私も妥当な推測だと思います。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

推測に過ぎませんが、`editorRefreshScreen`関数では`HL_NONPRINT`に対して色変更のエスケープシーケンス(4byte)を2回出力していますから、4 + 1 + 4 = 9 ではないでしょうか？

https://github.com/antirez/kilo/blob/efd541bb6d272f953e049a85d411765eed1a2979/kilo.c#L897-L905

Comment: nonprintは543行目(同一の関数内)で0になります。
そうなると`nonprint*9`は必ず0になってしまうのでしょうか?

Comment: リンク先バージョンを局所的に解釈すれば仰る通りですね。あとは[Le Pere d'OOさんコメント](http://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/29062/29065#comment27947_29062)の通りです。